# How to add an annotation to an attribute at runtime in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, annotations

Is it possible to add an annotation to an attribute or method at runtime in Groovy? I mean, in a more convenient way than using javaassist. I'm using grails 2.5.3.

Comment: You might be able to do it with some meta programming; however, it would depend somewhat on the type of annotation. A normal annotation could work, but an AST-base annotation would not apply the desired transformation since that would only happen during compilation.